# Custom view and url for DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to know how to add a custom view and url using DRF.

I currently have a `UserDetail(APIView)` class that can display a user object using a url like `/users/123/` but I'd like to also have the ability to view a users history with a url like `/users/123/history/` which would likely call on a new method within the `UserDetail` class. Is there a way to do this?

I've tried looking through DRFs documentation and it looks like they can achieve this through ViewSets and custom Routers, but I get errors when using ViewSets likes needing to define a `queryset`.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

Comment: Actually, that does work but I'd have to define the routes manually in the `urls.py` file like:

    url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+|me)/$', UserDetail.as_view({'get': 'get',})),
    url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+|me)/history/$', UserDetail.as_view({'get': 'history',}))

Is there a way to do that without bloating up the urls file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response

class UserDetail(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    @detail_route(methods=['GET'])
    def history(self, request, pk):
        user= self.get_object()
        serializer = UserCreateSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```